# How do I redirect to a specific action in a different controller in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3, controllers

I'm writing an API; in this API, I have a `FruitBasket` model which has `Fruits`. A particular Fruit may belong to more than one FruitBasket at a time. `FruitBasket` and `Fruit` are both `ActiveRecord` objects.

If someone performs a `GET` on `/fruit/100/baskets`, I want to provide a JSON list of baskets which have that fruit, in the form of basket IDs. If there's only one basket, I want to redirect to `/basket/x`, where `x` is the id of the basket. Something like this:

```
class FruitsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def baskets
    @baskets = Fruit.find(params[:id]).baskets
    if baskets.size == 1
      # What goes here?
    else
      respond_with @baskets
    end
  end
end
```

What do I put in my `routes` and the `FruitsController` to pull this off?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you really want to redirect them over there, but if you must:

```
...
if @baskets.size == 1
  redirect_to @baskets.first      
else
...
```

However, would expect an API to simple return an array of Baskets, and if there was only one basket, then it would be an array with one item.